On a scrollable element, how do I apply CSS properties to parts of its children that were hidden before scrolling?
Image 1 :

Image 2:

I have this element on my site that is supposed to scroll horizontally(overflow-x: scroll) on smaller screens, the issue is, the properties I applied to its children only appear on the parts the were visible before scrolling, in the example images you can see the background color is not the same throughout the elements, also it's not possible to interact with the area outside the selected part. I'll add this example to make my problem clearer.


function RenderPedidos() {
  return (
    pedidos.map((pedido, index) => ( <
      div key = {
        index
      }
      id = {
        index
      }
      name = "pedido"
      className = {
        (pedido.finalizado) ? "pedidos-container__content__pedido-finalizado" : "pedidos-container__content__pedido"
      }
      onClick = {
        event => handleClickPedido(event)
      } >
      <
      p > {
        (pedido.id > 9999) ? String(pedido.id).slice(0, 4) + '...' : pedido.id
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        (pedido.nome.length > 20) ? pedido.nome.slice(0, 21) + '...' : pedido.nome
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        (pedido.descricao.length > 35) ? pedido.descricao.slice(0, 36) + '...' : pedido.descricao
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        (pedido.material.length > 20) ? pedido.material.slice(0, 21) + '...' : pedido.material
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        "R$ " + pedido.valor.toFixed(2)
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        pedido.quantidade
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        (pedido.cliente.length > 20) ? pedido.cliente.slice(0, 21) + '...' : pedido.cliente
      } < /p> <
      p > {
        formatDatetime(pedido.prazo, 0)
      } < /p> <
      /div>
    ))
  )
}
&__content {
  margin-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 5px rgb(214, 214, 214);
  overflow-x: scroll;
  &__header {
    @include flex(1, 0);
    justify-content: start;
    p {
      @include flex(0, 0);
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      height: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      padding-right: 10px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(202, 202, 202);
      &:nth-child(1) {
        width: 60px;
        min-width: 60px
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 350px;
      }
      &:nth-child(4) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px
      }
      &:nth-child(5) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 150px
      }
      &:nth-child(6) {
        width: 60px;
        min-width: 60px
      }
      &:nth-child(7) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px;
      }
      &:nth-child(8) {
        width: 200px;
        min-width: 200px;
      }
    }
  }
  &__pedido,
  &__pedido-finalizado {
    @include flex(0, 0);
    justify-content: start;
    padding: 10px 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 125ms;
    &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247)
    }
    p {
      @include flex(0, 0);
      text-wrap: nowrap;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      padding-right: 10px;
      pointer-events: none;
      user-select: none;
      &:nth-child(1) {
        width: 60px;
        min-width: 60px
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px
      }
      &:nth-child(3) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 350px;
      }
      &:nth-child(4) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px
      }
      &:nth-child(5) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 150px
      }
      &:nth-child(6) {
        width: 60px;
        min-width: 60px
      }
      &:nth-child(7) {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 200px;
      }
      &:nth-child(8) {
        width: 200px;
        min-width: 200px;
      }
    }
  }
  &__pedido-finalizado {
    filter: opacity(25%);
    &:hover {
      background-color: rgb(221, 221, 221)
    }
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div className="pedidos-container__content">
  <div className="pedidos-container__content__header">
    <p>ID</p>
    <p>Nome</p>
    <p>Descrição</p>
    <p>Material</p>
    <p>Valor</p>
    <p>Qtd.</p>
    <p>Cliente</p>
    <p>Prazo</p>
  </div>
  <RenderPedidos/>
</div>



I tried to tinker with some properties but I had no meaningful outcome.

While I've converted your code to a running - albeit broken - snippet, I'd like to remind you that this is fundamentally a CSS problem, so the React isn't necessary to the demo. Rather than posting React code, and a JSX component, could you post the HTML that the React generates, as that isn't relevant to the problem and simply complicates the demo?

The problem has to do with the following three facts:

Paragraph tags are block-level elements.
The container is set to overflow, and is overflowing on its x-axis. This is caused by the container having a fixed width of 500px and the paragraph content width exceeding 500px.
The background-color is being applied on hover via a CSS style sheet.
How background-color on block-level elements work when points 1, 2, and 3 are true.

I don't know for certain, but it would appear that block-level elements only have a background-color on hover within the confines of its container property's width. However, when the display is set to inline, the p-tag's "block space" is no longer restricted by the 500px container limit. This is true because display inline doesn't set width based on its block level dimensions, but according to its content width dimensions (it's possible other CSS properties can be applied to further change it).


* {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  text-wrap: nowrap;
  display: inline;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}
<div id="container">
  <p>ID</p>
  <p>The Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) is a Kurdish-led coalition formed by ethnic militias and rebel groups, and serves as the official military wing of the ...</p>
</div>



The following text is extra reading, the text above technically solves OP question. The code below addresses an issue that many might not even recognize as a problem. However, in the event that some readers' do, I thought it was important to include it in my response.
This problem I speak of is how the p-tag will behave with display: inline. The p-tags content width will determine the p-tags width. If the content of the p-tag is less than that of the container width (500px), the background-color highlight effect will not extend the entire "row" that the p-tag is rendered on. Instead, the effect is limited to the width of the p-tag's content. One way to fix this is to render the p-tag as a block level when not overflowing, but then render it as inline when it is overflowing its parent container. This is the solution in the code below.


const isOverflowX = (element) => element.scrollWidth > element.clientWidth;

document.querySelectorAll('#container p').forEach(p => {
  if (isOverflowX(p)) {
    p.classList.add('inline');
  }
});
* {
  margin: 0;
}

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}
<div id="container">
  <p>ID</p>
  <p>The Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) is a Kurdish-led coalition formed by ethnic militias and rebel groups, and serves as the official military wing of the ...</p>
</div>



I have also made a React version solving the problem using an approach similar to the one I posted above, only combined with Gabriel F's. approach, which is at this codepen.

It was actually really simple to solve. All I had to do was assign the parent's scrollWidth to the children's width, using JS.
Check the codepen example.


const container = document.getElementById("container");
const text2 = document.getElementById("two");
text2.style.width = container.scrollWidth + "px";
* {
  margin: 0
}

body,
html {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%
}

#container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #b3b3b3;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  text-wrap: nowrap;
}

p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: white;
}
<div id="container">
  <p id="two">The Syrian Democratic Forces (SDF) is a Kurdish-led coalition formed by ethnic militias and rebel groups, and serves as the official military wing of the ...</p>
</div>




Hey Gabriel F. In your answer, you are recommending to directly manipulate the DOM. However, that is considered an anti-pattern in React applications. Instead of accessing and changing the elements directly like text2.style.width = container.scrollWidth + "px";, it would be best practice to use Refs instead. I made a codepen implementing this answer, only in a way that follows the rules of React.
